# Video download api google drive, php javascripts

Tags: php, google-drive-api

Good morning, I need a little special help.

I have a need with the google drive api, but I have no experience with it

I need to put on a website, a direct link to download files from google drive, that is, a button, that when pressed automatically starts the download if you leave the web.

The web application is based on php, html, and javascript

Can you help me a little to guide me? I'm very new to this api and I don't understand it at all...

And I would like that you will not need oauth to authenticate, just the button to download

Thanks...

Comment: You can make files public in Drive so you don't need to authenticate (for that you need to generate a sharing link, if I remember correctly), and you can get a direct URL link to them. But Google Drive is not a public filesharing service designed for lots of users to download from, so they impose limits on the number of downloads from a public link in a period of time. This might be ok for you depending on how many users you are expecting, but you should bear it in mind.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.